# Sqlite database connection best practice

Tags: multithreading, sqlite

I am using Sqlite database in an iOS app. I would like to confirm what is the best practice to use the connection. Is it ok to get connection for all database calls or create a static connection varible and  reuse it.

Currently i have some thing below but some times i get database busy error

```
    public SQLiteConnection CreateConnectionString()
    {
        SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(databsePath);

        return conn;
    }


    public Employee GetEmployeeObject()
    {
        Employee amp = null;

        var conn = CreateConnectionString();
        var employeeObj = conn.Table< Employee >();

        return employeeObj;
    }


    public void InsertEmployeeData(Object inserObject)
    {

        var conn = CreateConnectionString();

        using (conn)
        {
            conn.Insert(inserObject);
        }

    }
```

If multiple threads are trying to insert then i get Database Busy error. There are many posts on this issue but i couldn't find the exact solution.

Comment: Connection String != Connection

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to re-create a database connection for every database access.

But multiple threads would interfere with each other. So each thread should get its own connection.

Comment: Then how to handle multiple threads doing inserts or updates

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Off course i want to do it because there is requirement. I have some services updating database values same time inserting new rows. And, thats where i am seeing Database busy error

Comment: Late reply I guess, but to manage multiple thread upserting to  SQLite database, check out SQLITE_THREADSAFE = 1 as a compile-time option. Alternatively, switch to PRAGMA WAL_JOURNAL_MODE and use 1 connection per thread. In this manner you can achieve thread safety for IOS SQLite3

Comment: @whoblitz SQLITE_THREADSAFE does not prevent multiple threads from interfering with each other's transactions.